# Error with Vuetify colors in IE11

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, babel-polyfill

I am trying to use vuetify with Internet Explorer 11.

I have installed babel polyfill into my project.

but I am still getting errors. It looks like it is in the colors.js file.

Would anyone have any knowledge on what is causing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error Log:

```
/*!*************************************************!*\
!*** ./node_modules/vuetify/src/util/colors.js ***!
\*************************************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\nconst red = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#f44336',\n  lighten5: '#ffebee',\n  lighten4: '#ffcdd2',\n  lighten3: '#ef9a9a',\n  lighten2: '#e57373',\n  lighten1: '#ef5350',\n  darken1: '#e53935',\n  darken2: '#d32f2f',\n  darken3: '#c62828',\n  darken4: '#b71c1c',\n  accent1: '#ff8a80',\n  accent2: '#ff5252',\n  accent3: '#ff1744',\n  accent4: '#d50000'\n})\n\nconst pink = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#e91e63',\n  lighten5: '#fce4ec',\n  lighten4: '#f8bbd0',\n  lighten3: '#f48fb1',\n  lighten2: '#f06292',\n  lighten1: '#ec407a',\n  darken1: '#d81b60',\n  darken2: '#c2185b',\n  darken3: '#ad1457',\n  darken4: '#880e4f',\n  accent1: '#ff80ab',\n  accent2: '#ff4081',\n  accent3: '#f50057',\n  accent4: '#c51162'\n})\n\nconst purple = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#9c27b0',\n  lighten5: '#f3e5f5',\n  lighten4: '#e1bee7',\n  lighten3: '#ce93d8',\n  lighten2: '#ba68c8',\n  lighten1: '#ab47bc',\n  darken1: '#8e24aa',\n  darken2: '#7b1fa2',\n  darken3: '#6a1b9a',\n  darken4: '#4a148c',\n  accent1: '#ea80fc',\n  accent2: '#e040fb',\n  accent3: '#d500f9',\n  accent4: '#aa00ff'\n})\n\nconst deepPurple = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#673ab7',\n  lighten5: '#ede7f6',\n  lighten4: '#d1c4e9',\n  lighten3: '#b39ddb',\n  lighten2: '#9575cd',\n  lighten1: '#7e57c2',\n  darken1: '#5e35b1',\n  darken2: '#512da8',\n  darken3: '#4527a0',\n  darken4: '#311b92',\n  accent1: '#b388ff',\n  accent2: '#7c4dff',\n  accent3: '#651fff',\n  accent4: '#6200ea'\n})\n\nconst indigo = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#3f51b5',\n  lighten5: '#e8eaf6',\n  lighten4: '#c5cae9',\n  lighten3: '#9fa8da',\n  lighten2: '#7986cb',\n  lighten1: '#5c6bc0',\n  darken1: '#3949ab',\n  darken2: '#303f9f',\n  darken3: '#283593',\n  darken4: '#1a237e',\n  accent1: '#8c9eff',\n  accent2: '#536dfe',\n  accent3: '#3d5afe',\n  accent4: '#304ffe'\n})\n\nconst blue = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#2196f3',\n  lighten5: '#e3f2fd',\n  lighten4: '#bbdefb',\n  lighten3: '#90caf9',\n  lighten2: '#64b5f6',\n  lighten1: '#42a5f5',\n  darken1: '#1e88e5',\n  darken2: '#1976d2',\n  darken3: '#1565c0',\n  darken4: '#0d47a1',\n  accent1: '#82b1ff',\n  accent2: '#448aff',\n  accent3: '#2979ff',\n  accent4: '#2962ff'\n})\n\nconst lightBlue = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#03a9f4',\n  lighten5: '#e1f5fe',\n  lighten4: '#b3e5fc',\n  lighten3: '#81d4fa',\n  lighten2: '#4fc3f7',\n  lighten1: '#29b6f6',\n  darken1: '#039be5',\n  darken2: '#0288d1',\n  darken3: '#0277bd',\n  darken4: '#01579b',\n  accent1: '#80d8ff',\n  accent2: '#40c4ff',\n  accent3: '#00b0ff',\n  accent4: '#0091ea'\n})\n\nconst cyan = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#00bcd4',\n  lighten5: '#e0f7fa',\n  lighten4: '#b2ebf2',\n  lighten3: '#80deea',\n  lighten2: '#4dd0e1',\n  lighten1: '#26c6da',\n  darken1: '#00acc1',\n  darken2: '#0097a7',\n  darken3: '#00838f',\n  darken4: '#006064',\n  accent1: '#84ffff',\n  accent2: '#18ffff',\n  accent3: '#00e5ff',\n  accent4: '#00b8d4'\n})\n\nconst teal = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#009688',\n  lighten5: '#e0f2f1',\n  lighten4: '#b2dfdb',\n  lighten3: '#80cbc4',\n  lighten2: '#4db6ac',\n  lighten1: '#26a69a',\n  darken1: '#00897b',\n  darken2: '#00796b',\n  darken3: '#00695c',\n  darken4: '#004d40',\n  accent1: '#a7ffeb',\n  accent2: '#64ffda',\n  accent3: '#1de9b6',\n  accent4: '#00bfa5'\n})\n\nconst green = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#4caf50',\n  lighten5: '#e8f5e9',\n  lighten4: '#c8e6c9',\n  lighten3: '#a5d6a7',\n  lighten2: '#81c784',\n  lighten1: '#66bb6a',\n  darken1: '#43a047',\n  darken2: '#388e3c',\n  darken3: '#2e7d32',\n  darken4: '#1b5e20',\n  accent1: '#b9f6ca',\n  accent2: '#69f0ae',\n  accent3: '#00e676',\n  accent4: '#00c853'\n})\n\nconst lightGreen = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#8bc34a',\n  lighten5: '#f1f8e9',\n  lighten4: '#dcedc8',\n  lighten3: '#c5e1a5',\n  lighten2: '#aed581',\n  lighten1: '#9ccc65',\n  darken1: '#7cb342',\n  darken2: '#689f38',\n  darken3: '#558b2f',\n  darken4: '#33691e',\n  accent1: '#ccff90',\n  accent2: '#b2ff59',\n  accent3: '#76ff03',\n  accent4: '#64dd17'\n})\n\nconst lime = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#cddc39',\n  lighten5: '#f9fbe7',\n  lighten4: '#f0f4c3',\n  lighten3: '#e6ee9c',\n  lighten2: '#dce775',\n  lighten1: '#d4e157',\n  darken1: '#c0ca33',\n  darken2: '#afb42b',\n  darken3: '#9e9d24',\n  darken4: '#827717',\n  accent1: '#f4ff81',\n  accent2: '#eeff41',\n  accent3: '#c6ff00',\n  accent4: '#aeea00'\n})\n\nconst yellow = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#ffeb3b',\n  lighten5: '#fffde7',\n  lighten4: '#fff9c4',\n  lighten3: '#fff59d',\n  lighten2: '#fff176',\n  lighten1: '#ffee58',\n  darken1: '#fdd835',\n  darken2: '#fbc02d',\n  darken3: '#f9a825',\n  darken4: '#f57f17',\n  accent1: '#ffff8d',\n  accent2: '#ffff00',\n  accent3: '#ffea00',\n  accent4: '#ffd600'\n})\n\nconst amber = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#ffc107',\n  lighten5: '#fff8e1',\n  lighten4: '#ffecb3',\n  lighten3: '#ffe082',\n  lighten2: '#ffd54f',\n  lighten1: '#ffca28',\n  darken1: '#ffb300',\n  darken2: '#ffa000',\n  darken3: '#ff8f00',\n  darken4: '#ff6f00',\n  accent1: '#ffe57f',\n  accent2: '#ffd740',\n  accent3: '#ffc400',\n  accent4: '#ffab00'\n})\n\nconst orange = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#ff9800',\n  lighten5: '#fff3e0',\n  lighten4: '#ffe0b2',\n  lighten3: '#ffcc80',\n  lighten2: '#ffb74d',\n  lighten1: '#ffa726',\n  darken1: '#fb8c00',\n  darken2: '#f57c00',\n  darken3: '#ef6c00',\n  darken4: '#e65100',\n  accent1: '#ffd180',\n  accent2: '#ffab40',\n  accent3: '#ff9100',\n  accent4: '#ff6d00'\n})\n\nconst deepOrange = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#ff5722',\n  lighten5: '#fbe9e7',\n  lighten4: '#ffccbc',\n  lighten3: '#ffab91',\n  lighten2: '#ff8a65',\n  lighten1: '#ff7043',\n  darken1: '#f4511e',\n  darken2: '#e64a19',\n  darken3: '#d84315',\n  darken4: '#bf360c',\n  accent1: '#ff9e80',\n  accent2: '#ff6e40',\n  accent3: '#ff3d00',\n  accent4: '#dd2c00'\n})\n\nconst brown = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#795548',\n  lighten5: '#efebe9',\n  lighten4: '#d7ccc8',\n  lighten3: '#bcaaa4',\n  lighten2: '#a1887f',\n  lighten1: '#8d6e63',\n  darken1: '#6d4c41',\n  darken2: '#5d4037',\n  darken3: '#4e342e',\n  darken4: '#3e2723'\n})\n\nconst blueGrey = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#607d8b',\n  lighten5: '#eceff1',\n  lighten4: '#cfd8dc',\n  lighten3: '#b0bec5',\n  lighten2: '#90a4ae',\n  lighten1: '#78909c',\n  darken1: '#546e7a',\n  darken2: '#455a64',\n  darken3: '#37474f',\n  darken4: '#263238'\n})\n\nconst grey = Object.freeze({\n  base: '#9e9e9e',\n  lighten5: '#fafafa',\n  lighten4: '#f5f5f5',\n  lighten3: '#eeeeee',\n  lighten2: '#e0e0e0',\n  lighten1: '#bdbdbd',\n  darken1: '#757575',\n  darken2: '#616161',\n  darken3: '#424242',\n  darken4: '#212121'\n})\n\nconst shades = Object.freeze({\n  black: '#000000',\n  white: '#ffffff',\n  transparent: 'transparent'\n})\n\n/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__[\"default\"] = (Object.freeze({\n  red,\n  pink,\n  purple,\n  deepPurple,\n  indigo,\n  blue,\n  lightBlue,\n  cyan,\n  teal,\n  green,\n  lightGreen,\n  lime,\n  yellow,\n  amber,\n  orange,\n  deepOrange,\n  brown,\n  blueGrey,\n  grey,\n  shades\n}));\n\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndlYnBhY2s6Ly8vLi9ub2RlX21vZHVsZXMvdnVldGlmeS9zcmMvdXRpbC9jb2xvcnMuanM/NTEyOSJdLCJuYW1lcyI6W10sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiQUFBQTtBQUFBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EsQ0FBQzs7QUFFRDtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EsQ0FBQzs7QUFFRDtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EsQ0FBQzs7QUFFRDtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EsQ0FBQzs7QUFFRDtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EsQ0FBQzs7QUFFRDtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUM7O0FBRUQ7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQSxDQUFDOztBQUVEO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBLENBQUMiLCJmaWxlIjoiLi9ub2RlX21vZHVsZXMvdnVldGlmeS9zcmMvdXRpbC9jb2xvcnMuanMuanMiLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyJjb25zdCByZWQgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyNmNDQzMzYnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmZmViZWUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNmZmNkZDInLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNlZjlhOWEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNlNTczNzMnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyNlZjUzNTAnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnI2U1MzkzNScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjZDMyZjJmJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyNjNjI4MjgnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnI2I3MWMxYycsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjZmY4YTgwJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNmZjUyNTInLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnI2ZmMTc0NCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjZDUwMDAwJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgcGluayA9IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICBiYXNlOiAnI2U5MWU2MycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW41OiAnI2ZjZTRlYycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW40OiAnI2Y4YmJkMCcsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4zOiAnI2Y0OGZiMScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4yOiAnI2YwNjI5MicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4xOiAnI2VjNDA3YScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjE6ICcjZDgxYjYwJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMjogJyNjMjE4NWInLFxuICBkYXJrZW4zOiAnI2FkMTQ1NycsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjQ6ICcjODgwZTRmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MTogJyNmZjgwYWInLFxuICBhY2NlbnQyOiAnI2ZmNDA4MScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDM6ICcjZjUwMDU3JyxcbiAgYWNjZW50NDogJyNjNTExNjInXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCBwdXJwbGUgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyM5YzI3YjAnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmM2U1ZjUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNlMWJlZTcnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNjZTkzZDgnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNiYTY4YzgnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyNhYjQ3YmMnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnIzhlMjRhYScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjN2IxZmEyJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyM2YTFiOWEnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnIzRhMTQ4YycsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjZWE4MGZjJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNlMDQwZmInLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnI2Q1MDBmOScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjYWEwMGZmJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgZGVlcFB1cnBsZSA9IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICBiYXNlOiAnIzY3M2FiNycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW41OiAnI2VkZTdmNicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW40OiAnI2QxYzRlOScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4zOiAnI2IzOWRkYicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4yOiAnIzk1NzVjZCcsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4xOiAnIzdlNTdjMicsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjE6ICcjNWUzNWIxJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMjogJyM1MTJkYTgnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4zOiAnIzQ1MjdhMCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjQ6ICcjMzExYjkyJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MTogJyNiMzg4ZmYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQyOiAnIzdjNGRmZicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDM6ICcjNjUxZmZmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50NDogJyM2MjAwZWEnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCBpbmRpZ28gPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyMzZjUxYjUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNlOGVhZjYnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNjNWNhZTknLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyM5ZmE4ZGEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyM3OTg2Y2InLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyM1YzZiYzAnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnIzM5NDlhYicsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjMzAzZjlmJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyMyODM1OTMnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnIzFhMjM3ZScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjOGM5ZWZmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyM1MzZkZmUnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnIzNkNWFmZScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjMzA0ZmZlJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgYmx1ZSA9IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICBiYXNlOiAnIzIxOTZmMycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW41OiAnI2UzZjJmZCcsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW40OiAnI2JiZGVmYicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4zOiAnIzkwY2FmOScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4yOiAnIzY0YjVmNicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4xOiAnIzQyYTVmNScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjE6ICcjMWU4OGU1JyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMjogJyMxOTc2ZDInLFxuICBkYXJrZW4zOiAnIzE1NjVjMCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjQ6ICcjMGQ0N2ExJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MTogJyM4MmIxZmYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQyOiAnIzQ0OGFmZicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDM6ICcjMjk3OWZmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50NDogJyMyOTYyZmYnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCBsaWdodEJsdWUgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyMwM2E5ZjQnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNlMWY1ZmUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNiM2U1ZmMnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyM4MWQ0ZmEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyM0ZmMzZjcnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyMyOWI2ZjYnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnIzAzOWJlNScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjMDI4OGQxJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyMwMjc3YmQnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnIzAxNTc5YicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjODBkOGZmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyM0MGM0ZmYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnIzAwYjBmZicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjMDA5MWVhJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgY3lhbiA9IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICBiYXNlOiAnIzAwYmNkNCcsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW41OiAnI2UwZjdmYScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW40OiAnI2IyZWJmMicsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4zOiAnIzgwZGVlYScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4yOiAnIzRkZDBlMScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4xOiAnIzI2YzZkYScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjE6ICcjMDBhY2MxJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMjogJyMwMDk3YTcnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4zOiAnIzAwODM4ZicsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjQ6ICcjMDA2MDY0JyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MTogJyM4NGZmZmYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQyOiAnIzE4ZmZmZicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDM6ICcjMDBlNWZmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50NDogJyMwMGI4ZDQnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCB0ZWFsID0gT2JqZWN0LmZyZWV6ZSh7XG4gIGJhc2U6ICcjMDA5Njg4JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjU6ICcjZTBmMmYxJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjQ6ICcjYjJkZmRiJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjM6ICcjODBjYmM0JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjI6ICcjNGRiNmFjJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjE6ICcjMjZhNjlhJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMTogJyMwMDg5N2InLFxuICBkYXJrZW4yOiAnIzAwNzk2YicsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjM6ICcjMDA2OTVjJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuNDogJyMwMDRkNDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQxOiAnI2E3ZmZlYicsXG4gIGFjY2VudDI6ICcjNjRmZmRhJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MzogJyMxZGU5YjYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQ0OiAnIzAwYmZhNSdcbn0pXG5cbmNvbnN0IGdyZWVuID0gT2JqZWN0LmZyZWV6ZSh7XG4gIGJhc2U6ICcjNGNhZjUwJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjU6ICcjZThmNWU5JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjQ6ICcjYzhlNmM5JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjM6ICcjYTVkNmE3JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjI6ICcjODFjNzg0JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjE6ICcjNjZiYjZhJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMTogJyM0M2EwNDcnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4yOiAnIzM4OGUzYycsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjM6ICcjMmU3ZDMyJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuNDogJyMxYjVlMjAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQxOiAnI2I5ZjZjYScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDI6ICcjNjlmMGFlJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MzogJyMwMGU2NzYnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQ0OiAnIzAwYzg1Mydcbn0pXG5cbmNvbnN0IGxpZ2h0R3JlZW4gPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyM4YmMzNGEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmMWY4ZTknLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNkY2VkYzgnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNjNWUxYTUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNhZWQ1ODEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyM5Y2NjNjUnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnIzdjYjM0MicsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjNjg5ZjM4JyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyM1NThiMmYnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnIzMzNjkxZScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjY2NmZjkwJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNiMmZmNTknLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnIzc2ZmYwMycsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjNjRkZDE3J1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgbGltZSA9IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICBiYXNlOiAnI2NkZGMzOScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW41OiAnI2Y5ZmJlNycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW40OiAnI2YwZjRjMycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4zOiAnI2U2ZWU5YycsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4yOiAnI2RjZTc3NScsXG4gIGxpZ2h0ZW4xOiAnI2Q0ZTE1NycsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjE6ICcjYzBjYTMzJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMjogJyNhZmI0MmInLFxuICBkYXJrZW4zOiAnIzllOWQyNCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjQ6ICcjODI3NzE3JyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MTogJyNmNGZmODEnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQyOiAnI2VlZmY0MScsXG4gIGFjY2VudDM6ICcjYzZmZjAwJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50NDogJyNhZWVhMDAnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCB5ZWxsb3cgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyNmZmViM2InLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmZmZkZTcnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNmZmY5YzQnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNmZmY1OWQnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNmZmYxNzYnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyNmZmVlNTgnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnI2ZkZDgzNScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjZmJjMDJkJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyNmOWE4MjUnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnI2Y1N2YxNycsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjZmZmZjhkJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNmZmZmMDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnI2ZmZWEwMCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjZmZkNjAwJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgYW1iZXIgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyNmZmMxMDcnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmZmY4ZTEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNmZmVjYjMnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNmZmUwODInLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNmZmQ1NGYnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyNmZmNhMjgnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnI2ZmYjMwMCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjZmZhMDAwJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyNmZjhmMDAnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnI2ZmNmYwMCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjZmZlNTdmJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNmZmQ3NDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnI2ZmYzQwMCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjZmZhYjAwJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3Qgb3JhbmdlID0gT2JqZWN0LmZyZWV6ZSh7XG4gIGJhc2U6ICcjZmY5ODAwJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjU6ICcjZmZmM2UwJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjQ6ICcjZmZlMGIyJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjM6ICcjZmZjYzgwJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjI6ICcjZmZiNzRkJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjE6ICcjZmZhNzI2JyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMTogJyNmYjhjMDAnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4yOiAnI2Y1N2MwMCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjM6ICcjZWY2YzAwJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuNDogJyNlNjUxMDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQxOiAnI2ZmZDE4MCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDI6ICcjZmZhYjQwJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MzogJyNmZjkxMDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQ0OiAnI2ZmNmQwMCdcbn0pXG5cbmNvbnN0IGRlZXBPcmFuZ2UgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyNmZjU3MjInLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNmYmU5ZTcnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNmZmNjYmMnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNmZmFiOTEnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNmZjhhNjUnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyNmZjcwNDMnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnI2Y0NTExZScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjZTY0YTE5JyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyNkODQzMTUnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnI2JmMzYwYycsXG4gIGFjY2VudDE6ICcjZmY5ZTgwJyxcbiAgYWNjZW50MjogJyNmZjZlNDAnLFxuICBhY2NlbnQzOiAnI2ZmM2QwMCcsXG4gIGFjY2VudDQ6ICcjZGQyYzAwJ1xufSlcblxuY29uc3QgYnJvd24gPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmFzZTogJyM3OTU1NDgnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNTogJyNlZmViZTknLFxuICBsaWdodGVuNDogJyNkN2NjYzgnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMzogJyNiY2FhYTQnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMjogJyNhMTg4N2YnLFxuICBsaWdodGVuMTogJyM4ZDZlNjMnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4xOiAnIzZkNGM0MScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjI6ICcjNWQ0MDM3JyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMzogJyM0ZTM0MmUnLFxuICBkYXJrZW40OiAnIzNlMjcyMydcbn0pXG5cbmNvbnN0IGJsdWVHcmV5ID0gT2JqZWN0LmZyZWV6ZSh7XG4gIGJhc2U6ICcjNjA3ZDhiJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjU6ICcjZWNlZmYxJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjQ6ICcjY2ZkOGRjJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjM6ICcjYjBiZWM1JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjI6ICcjOTBhNGFlJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjE6ICcjNzg5MDljJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMTogJyM1NDZlN2EnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4yOiAnIzQ1NWE2NCcsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjM6ICcjMzc0NzRmJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuNDogJyMyNjMyMzgnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCBncmV5ID0gT2JqZWN0LmZyZWV6ZSh7XG4gIGJhc2U6ICcjOWU5ZTllJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjU6ICcjZmFmYWZhJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjQ6ICcjZjVmNWY1JyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjM6ICcjZWVlZWVlJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjI6ICcjZTBlMGUwJyxcbiAgbGlnaHRlbjE6ICcjYmRiZGJkJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuMTogJyM3NTc1NzUnLFxuICBkYXJrZW4yOiAnIzYxNjE2MScsXG4gIGRhcmtlbjM6ICcjNDI0MjQyJyxcbiAgZGFya2VuNDogJyMyMTIxMjEnXG59KVxuXG5jb25zdCBzaGFkZXMgPSBPYmplY3QuZnJlZXplKHtcbiAgYmxhY2s6ICcjMDAwMDAwJyxcbiAgd2hpdGU6ICcjZmZmZmZmJyxcbiAgdHJhbnNwYXJlbnQ6ICd0cmFuc3BhcmVudCdcbn0pXG5cbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IE9iamVjdC5mcmVlemUoe1xuICByZWQsXG4gIHBpbmssXG4gIHB1cnBsZSxcbiAgZGVlcFB1cnBsZSxcbiAgaW5kaWdvLFxuICBibHVlLFxuICBsaWdodEJsdWUsXG4gIGN5YW4sXG4gIHRlYWwsXG4gIGdyZWVuLFxuICBsaWdodEdyZWVuLFxuICBsaW1lLFxuICB5ZWxsb3csXG4gIGFtYmVyLFxuICBvcmFuZ2UsXG4gIGRlZXBPcmFuZ2UsXG4gIGJyb3duLFxuICBibHVlR3JleSxcbiAgZ3JleSxcbiAgc2hhZGVzXG59KVxuIl0sInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIifQ==\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/src/util/colors.js\n");

 /***/ }),

 /***/ "./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js":
 /*!********************************************!*\
 !*** ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js ***!
 \********************************************/
 /*! exports provided: Store, install, mapState, mapMutations, mapGetters, 
 mapActions, createNamespacedHelpers, default */
 /***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {
```

---

Error log from internet explorer:

[image: error log from internet explorer]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I recommend posting your error as text, as not everyone can read the fine details & do research with a picture

Comment: The code posted is the part where I am getting an error. There are about 9000 lines of code in the console. How should i post the other lines ?

Comment: I was asking for your error, some people including me use stackoverflow from networks that filter images

Comment: @Ferrybig i soved it! It was a problem with one of my store modules having a separate import colors from vuetify statement. Thank you for your help!